# How to recover BTC that wasn't converted into ETH by Shifty via Mist?

Tags: exchanges, shapeshift

- I tried the "deposit with BTC" option
- BTC transfer was recognized in "Awaiting Deposit"
- Then "Awaiting Exchange" timed out, I got a "try again" dialog, and was shown no way to get my BTC back or to try only the exchange part again without a new BTC deposit.

How do I get either my BTC back or the ETH I paid for? Who should I talk to, ShapeShift or Ethereum?

Comment: Although the interface threw up, 20min later the ETH was credited to my account without any further intervention, so I guess this is answered for now. Might be useful to keep the question around so others with the same problem can find some reassurance.

Comment: Unless they got the same error and are wondering whether they lost their BTC forever.

Comment: I would suggest answering your own question, then marking it as answered. I don't think it needs to be closed, and is definitely on-topic

Comment: It's because the [Bitcoin network is full](https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions).

Comment: Also make sure to always include a return address with ShapeShift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the interface threw up, 20min later the ETH was credited to my account without any further intervention, so I guess this is answered for now. Might be useful to keep the question around so others with the same problem can find some reassurance.

Answer (score 1):

Contact the [shapeshift support](https://shapeshift.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) and request a refund if your funds are not credited within 30 minutes.

For reporting it's most likely sufficient to provide a valid bitcoin transaction id of the deposit.

I've been through this process and they respond and refund very fast.