# Ethereum Deposited Using Bitcoin Not Showing

Tags: mist, wallets, bitcoin, coinbase

On 6/13, from Mist, I went through the "Deposit using Bitcon" option. My BTC are in Coinbase and as far as Coinbase is concerned, the transaction is confirmed. But, the Ethereum are not showing in my wallet. I tried looking up my address in Etherscan, but it also shows 0 Ethereum. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have a transaction ID?

Comment: same for me, it shows 0 on my wallet. Though, on another window it confirmed that the bitcoins were received, changed to Ethereums and transferred to my wallet adress.

Comment: Turns out there was another post just like mine here:  http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/how-to-recover-btc-that-wasnt-converted-into-eth-by-shifty-via-mist

I contacted ShapeShift support and they were able to reverse the transaction