# Kinda stuck, seeking guidance, can't see/find ETH

Tags: mist, wallets, accounts, synchronization, shapeshift

Series of events:

- Got excited about Ethereum and began to download Ethereum Wallet (7/14/2016)
- When prompted (before blockchain synched), I transferred about 2 BTC to my "Master Account" in three separate transfers (within about a 4 hour period)
- Blockchain continued to synch (at about 6000 blocks per minute)
- Flipped back and forth between menus talking about recipes for crowdfunding/DAO/currency... Then went to far "back" and reached the "create account" page at the front...
- The only way to proceed was to create another account, so I did. (I later learn that this public key is now a secondary account after my Master Account)
- Because I created 2 accounts (on accident, really), the blockchain began synching A SECOND TIME, and has been MUCH MUCH SLOWER (60 blocks a minute).  At this rate, it will take over 10 days to synch if running continuously
- When I launch the Wallet (after a break from synching), then "skip" to the application, I can see that there are 2 accounts... The Master Account and the second account I accidentally created.  Both accounts show 0 ETH

Question:

Where are my ETH?  Do I need to wait for blockchain to finish synching before the ETH will be visible in the Ethereum Wallet?  If so, what can I do to speed up the synching process?

Comment: how did you tranfer 2 BTC to your Masteraccount? Did you convert the BTC on an Exchange?

Comment: I used the Ethereum Wallet transfer menu that appears as the program first opens to start synching.  I first transferred a small amount to confirm that the BTC exited my bitcoin wallet... Then transferred two larger amounts totaling 2 BTC between the three transfers

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Answer [for slow mist sync here](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/603/87) and [troubleshoot bitcoin transactions to your wallet here](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1717/87).

Comment: Bzw if you think you can send btc to ethereum wallet you are wrong