# Ethereum wallet income - transaction time

Tags: transactions

Can someone give me a hint please I'm new to Ethereum and I transfered/funded a small value of bitcoin (2 ETH) to Etherum official desktop wallet downloaded from GitHub and after I completed transaction on Blockchain it said funds are transfered to my Main Account (Etherbase) address the same address as mentioned on my desktop app it's been for an hour now but still says Balance 0.00 Ether on desktop application.

How long does it take for the Balance to get updated ?

**Update**

After reviewing my email I followed the link received from *shapeshift.io* from which I can see this picture:

[image]

As far as I see this address received ETHs but how do I get access to them if on my desktop wallet it still says *0 Balance*. ?

Comment: Did you send Bitcoin to the [wallet integrated shapeshift functionality - see this](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1717/87). Regarding [balance not showing - see this](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3869/87).

Comment: yes using a wallet desktop app I click an option fund with bitcoin it opened other window where to transfer bitcoin using shapeshift.. I will try to check later maybe it takes time

Comment: also as I read in your comment link maybe I should wait until it's fully synced

Comment: Did you check the transaction on shapeshift using email address followup? Your bitcoin transaction might be late as it has a large backlog. But once that clears ETH should be seen in your account. Check the email to see the transaction and follow up on the number of confirmations (I see that you question was asked just 4 hours ago, so I am guessing it is still in the process of confirmation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

Still not sure how this happened... but this is what I did on my Ubuntu machine.

Firstly I removed *ethereum-wallet* with [*gdebi*](https://launchpad.net/gdebi) tool and downloaded *Mist* wallet from the same source at [*GitHub*](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases) and installed it with *gdebi* as well as command line tools:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ethereum
```

After that I ran:

```
geth updatedb
geth --fast
```

And leave it overnight and in the morning my balance on desktop wallet was *2 Ether*

Maybe this will help some people as well.